# how to create zip file on a absolute path using zipfile

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I am trying to create a zip file of files from different directories. At the end, I want to save that zip file to a different path than python file python.
I have the following code snippet

```
def zipfile_method(file_list):
    try:
        zip_path = os.path.abspath('/Users/nirmalsarswat/Document/jdk.zip')
        print(zip_path)
        zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        for files in file_list:
            path = os.path.abspath(files)
            zip_file.write(path)
        zip_file.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception occured during compression %s" % e)


zipfile_method(['/Users/nirmalsarswat/Desktop/jdk-8u171-macosx-x64.dmg', '/Users/nirmalsarswat/Desktop/resume-nirmal-sarswat.pdf'])
```

Path of my python file is `/Users/nirmalsarswat/Desktop/app.py`.

I expect that file path would be on `/Users/nirmalsarswat/Document/jdk.zip` but zipfile saves it on the same folder of python file like this `/Users/nirmalsarswat/Desktop/Users/nirmalsarswat/Document/jdk.zip`.

How I can make to save the file on `/Users/nirmalsarswat/Document/jdk.zip` path

I am using MacOS, Python 3.6.4.

Comment: Your function references a `path` (in `zip_file.write(path)`) but I don't see that being defined so you may want to check that line does what you're expecting.

Comment: @jedwards please see this `path = os.path.abspath(files)`

Comment: @jedwards files are getting saved to zip but the zip is not actually going to saved on the directory where I want to.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood -- whats your intention behind calling `abspath`?  If you `print(zip_path)` do you not see the *incorrect* path?

Comment: I was just crosschecking whether the string path is same as `os.path.abspath()` or not

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear, my suggestion is that you write `zip_path = '/Users/nirmalsarswat/Document/jdk.zip'` and *not* call `abspath` (as it seems you're *already* supplying an absolute path).

Comment: @jedwards that didn't worked before so I tried this way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what I can see is, you are doing correct but you are confused with paths. When you pass the only absolute path to `write`, it will zip the file with a complete directory which seems the problem you are facing.

Try parsing `basename` with `write` and it will work fine, like this

```
from os.path import basename # add this to your imports
def zipfile_method(file_list):
    try:
        zip_path = os.path.abspath('/Users/nirmalsarswat/Document/jdk.zip') # no need to this one, parse string itself
        print(zip_path)
        zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        for files in file_list:
            path = os.path.abspath(files)
            zip_file.write(path, basename(path))
        zip_file.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception occured during compression %s" % e)


zipfile_method(['/Users/nirmalsarswat/Desktop/jdk-8u171-macosx-x64.dmg', '/Users/nirmalsarswat/Desktop/resume-nirmal-sarswat.pdf'])
```

Comment: thanks :+1:, I was actually confused with the path so I thought that zip is not on correct path.